# Why is the output of element-wise addition/subtraction different depending on whether my numpy array is of type int64 or uint8?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm doing image comparisons and calculating diff's and have noticed that element-wise subtraction only seems to work when I read the data in as a numpy array with dtype='int64' and not with dtype='uint8'. I'd like to switch to 'unit8' for image visualization reasons.

```
image1 = np.array(plt.imread('fixed_image.jpg'), dtype='int64')[:, :, 0:3]
image2 = np.array(plt.imread('fixed_image_2.jpg'), dtype='int64')[:, :, 0:3]
diff = image1-image2
```

In the code above, diff is only calculated correctly with dtype int64 and not with dtype uint8. Why is that?

Comment: You can solve this by doing `diff = (image1-image2).astype('uint8')`

Comment: Compare `c-c[::-1]` for some range of numbers, such as `np.arange(0,256)` for the 2 dtypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uint8` means "8 bit unsigned integer" and **only has valid values in 0-255**.  This is because 256 distinct values is the maximum amount that can be represented using 8 bits of data.  If you add two uint8 images together, you'll very likely overflow 255 somewhere.  For example:

```
>>> np.uint8(130) + np.uint8(131)
5
```

Similarly, if you subtract two images, you'll very likely get negative numbers - which get wrapped around to the high end of the range again:

```
>>> np.uint8(130) - np.uint8(131)
255
```

If you need to add or subtract images like this, you'll want to work with a dtype that won't underflow/overflow as easily (e.g. int64 or float), then normalize and convert back to uint8 as the last step.